# Legacy VC++ application on Windows 7 / 10

Tags: odbc, windows-10, legacy-app

Is it possible that an application that works fine in Windows XP wouldn't work at all in Windows 7 / 10? If not, what would be the steps to make it work?

I know the following about the application:

- It is based on VC++
- It uses DDE to communicate with MS Word (2000)
- It uses ODBC32 for a db connection

Comment: Our crystal ball is out of service ;) We can't tell if it works or not. Test your software on Win7/10

Comment: :) Of course I tested it, and it doesn't. That's why I have supplied some additional info, maybe someone knows a general answer.

Comment: use remote debugger to debug the tool under Win7/10 and look what fails

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors, but do try some of the things I tried with a similar issue: [Error loading database on Lyrix.exe (Delphi 7 legacy application) on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937771/error-loading-database-on-lyrix-exe-delphi-7-legacy-application-on-windows-10/39937772#39937772)